# Can sql_actions_Local_instance_MySQL56.log be deleted?

Tags: mysql, logfile

I have a log file under Users>MyUser>AppData>Roaming>MySQL>Workbench>log with 9.1 GB of size.

Its name is sql_actions_Local_instance_MySQL56.log , I was wondering if I could simply delete it without breaking anything?

Also why is the file so large and what does it contain? Notepad++ is unable to open the massive file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html#wb-configuring-files-log), those are logs of all SQL execution results but without the data, for debugging purposes.

so I think you can safely delete them.

Hope this helps!